# Where I can found the SignalR core polyfills for Node

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core-signalr

In the [SignalR npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr#nodejs) says, that in order to use from Node we should include some polyfills

> The following polyfills are required to use the client in Node.js applications:
>
> `XmlHttpRequest` - always
>
> `WebSockets` - to use the WebSockets transport
>
> `EventSource` - to use the ServerSentEvents transport
>
> `btoa/atob` - to use binary protocols (e.g. MessagePack) over text transports (ServerSentEvents)

And the question is, have anybody a link to those polyfills?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For future references:

The answer seems to be [here](http://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2284)